# Pass arguments in Slim DI service

Tags: php, slim

I have a service that I want to access from a route but pass arguments to.

```
$container = new \Slim\Container();    
$container['myService'] = function($arg1, $arg2) {
        //my code here
};
$app = new \Slim\App($container);
```

and inside my route, I try to call the service like so:

```
$this->myService('my arg1', 'my arg2');
```

This is not working. When I try to call it without specifying the arguments, it works.

How to call with arguments? Or is that an alternative way to specify a function or method to be called from inside a route?

Comment: Slim3. Trying to call from inside a GET route

Comment: Shouldn't be dependent on whether they are get arguments? Just want to be able to pass values to a service from within a route (PUT, GET, etc)

Comment: would be really helpful if you setup an example. new to slim.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

so you are pretty close.

```
$container = new \Slim\Container();    
$container['myService'] = function ($c) { 
    return function($arg1, $arg2) {
        //my code here
    }
};
$app = new \Slim\App($container);

$app->get('/', function ($req, $res, $args) {
    $this->myService($a, $b);
});
```

This should work.

Optionally, with your original code... you have to save it to a variable first before invoking it.

```
$service = $this->myService;
$service('my arg1', 'my arg2');
```

Both of these should work.

Comment: This answer is not accurate. `$this->myService($a, $b);` should raise a fatal error `Call to undefined method Slim\Container::myService()` which it does. The second method mentioned works as expected.